# Collapse control characters in text file (pseudoconsole)

Tags: c#, .net, python, bash

I have a text file it includes various control characters including backspace `\b` and carriage return `\r`. For example

```
100\r101\r102\r103
£\b$\b%
```

I'd like to 'collapse' these control characters to leave me with the text one would see in a console that understood these control characters:

> 103
>   %

I don't know what this is called. If it has a name, please share it, so  I can search for it.

Comment: How does [tag:bash] fit with [tag:c#] and [tag:.net]?

Comment: I hope there already exists an application that does what I describe. If not, maybe there's a library function in some programming language I can use. Otherwise, I'll write the function and application myself.

Comment: How can I move this to superuser?

Comment: Click on the flag link under the tags at the bottom of your question and ask a moderator to move it.

Answer (score -1):

i guess you can simply make a loop on it then replace the characters(backspace \b and carriage return \r) with ones that console could understand